# How to rewrite synchronous controller to be asynchronous in Play?

Tags: asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play framework 2.2 for one of my upcoming web application. I have implemented my controllers in synchronous pattern, with several blocking calls (mainly, database).

For example,

#### Synchronous version:

```
public static Result index(){
  User user = db.getUser(email); // blocking
  User anotherUser = db.getUser(emailTwo); // blocking
  ...
  user.sendEmail(); // call to a webservice, blocking.
  return ok();
}
```

So, while optimising the code, decided to make use of Asynchronous programming support of Play. Gone through the documentation, but the idea is still vague to me, as I'm confused about how to properly convert the above synchronous block of code to Async.

So, I came up with below code:

#### Asynchronous version:

```
public static Promise<Result> index(){
  return Promise.promise(
    new Function0<Result>(){
      public Result apply(){
        User user = db.getUser(email); // blocking
        User anotherUser = db.getUser(emailTwo); // blocking
        ...
        user.sendEmail(); // call to a webservice, blocking.
        return ok();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

So, I just wrapped the entire control logic inside a `promise` block.

1. Is my approach correct?
2. Should I convert each and every blocking request inside the controller, as Asynchronous, or wrapping several blocking calls inside single Async block is enough?

Comment: why did the title get edited??? I think the original title 'How to properly implement Async programming in Play framework?' was better since it isn't just about changing the controller but about implementing a complete non-blocking application flow. Just re-writing a synchronous controller will not make it asynchronous!

Comment: Is there any way that `user.sendEmail()` could be made non-blocking?

Comment: depends on what you use to send email, if you use for example Amazon Simple Email Service, you could use the AWS Java SDK which supports asynchronous emails. Or you can use the JavaMail API as described on http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkiez.html Do you think the client should be blocked until the email is send?

Answer (score 7):

The play framework is asynchronous by nature and it allows the creation of fully non-blocking code. But in order to be non-blocking - with all its benefits - you can't just wrap your blocking code and expect magic to happen...

In an ideal scenario, your complete application is written in a non-blocking manner. If this is not possible (for whatever reason), you might want to abstract your blocking code in Akka actors or behind *async interfaces* which return `scala.concurrent.Future`'s. This way you can execute your blocking code (simultaneously) in a dedicated Execution Context, without impacting other actions. After all, having all your actions share the same ExecutionContext means they share the same Thread pool. So an Action that blocks Threads might drastically impact other Actions doing pure CPU while having CPU not fully utilized!

In your case, you probably want to start at the lowest level. It looks like the database calls are blocking so start by refactoring these first. You either need to find an asynchronous driver for whatever database you are using or if there is only a blocking driver available, you should wrap them in a future to execute using a DB-specific execution context (with a ThreadPool that's the same size as the DB ConnectionPool).

Another advantage of abstracting the DB calls behind an *async interface* is that, if at some point in the future, you switch to a non-blocking driver, you can just change the implementation of your interface without having to change your controllers!

In your re-active controller, you can then handle these futures and work with them (when they complete). You can find more about working with Futures [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html)

Here's a simplified example of your controller method doing non-blocking calls, and then combining the results in your view, while sending an email asynchronous:

```
public static Promise<Result> index(){
    scala.concurrent.Future<User> user = db.getUser(email); // non-blocking
    scala.concurrent.Future<User> anotherUser = db.getUser(emailTwo); // non-blocking

    List<scala.concurrent.Future<User>> listOfUserFutures = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfUserFutures.add(user);
    listOfUserFutures.add(anotherUser);
    final ExecutionContext dbExecutionContext = Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("dbExecutionContext");
    scala.concurrent.Future<Iterable<User>> futureListOfUsers = akka.dispatch.Futures.sequence(listOfUserFutures, dbExecutionContext);  

    final ExecutionContext mailExecutionContext = Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("mailExecutionContext");
    user.andThen(new OnComplete<User>() {
        public void onComplete(Throwable failure, User user) {
             user.sendEmail(); // call to a webservice, non-blocking.       
        }
    }, mailExecutionContext);

    return Promise.wrap(futureListOfUsers.flatMap(new Mapper<Iterable<User>, Future<Result>>() {
        public Future<Result> apply(final Iterable<User> users) {
            return Futures.future(new Callable<Result>() {
                public Result call() {              
                    return ok(...);
                }
            }, Akka.system().dispatcher());
        }
    }, ec));
}
```

Comment: The web service calls using the play WS library are non-blocking. For DB calls, as is mentioned in the earlier post, you would have to see if your database server has a non-blocking driver. In my knowledge, only MongoDB has a non-blocking driver [link](http://reactivemongo.org)

Comment: I'm using MySQL with Play's EBean. So, I suppose it doesn't yet support Future?

Comment: I think EBean do support asynchronous queries... check http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_future.html

Answer (score 2):

It you don't have anything to not block on then there may not be a reason to make your controller async.  Here is a good blog about this from one of the creators of Play: http://sadache.tumblr.com/post/42351000773/async-reactive-nonblocking-threads-futures-executioncont

Comment: In my case, the DB calls (to MySQL, using play's EBean) are blocking, I guess. So, I should go for Async then?

Comment: You do not need to be Async.  There is no reason to.  Just use the regular controller that returns a `Result`.

Comment: Hey James, why do you say there is no reason to be async? The OP is asking for optimisations, don't you agree that being fully non-blocking and writing re-active code is an optimisation over being blocking? I agree that just wrapping your blocking code is pointless  but i don't understand why you recommend him to just keep what he has...

Comment: If the code can be non-blocking then it has to be async.  But if it can't be non-blocking then there is no reason to be async.  Play already handles all requests asynchronously under the covers.

Comment: My point is that when someone asks "How to properly implement Async programming in Play framework?", it's not the right answer to say 'you do not need to be async, there is no reason to'. Being Responsive has massive advantages, i know you know this. What bit of his code can't be non-blocking? He can use asynchronous ebean queries and at least send his email from an akka actor

Comment: JDBC is blocking and trying to wrap it in async doesn't afford any performance advantages.  There are definitely other reasons to put db stuff in actors but not for the sake of being async.

Comment: From the original question, you don't know that his DB is accessed using JDBC, it might be MongoDB. And even if he just puts these DB calls behind an interface which returns Futures, it allows him, for instance, to use memcached (which is non-blocking) when he doesn't need to access the actual database. And when he ever refactors to a non-blocking DB driver, he doesn't need to change all non-reactive code in his controllers. Oh and then he can retrieve both users simultaneously... Anyway, my point is that it would be better to teach people how to be non-blocking then to say don't be!

Comment: I agree.  But when the question specifically says the db calls are blocking and asks how to make the controller async, the right answer is "don't".  If the question was "how can I make this whole thing non-blocking?" then the answer is very different.

Comment: @JamesWard By using a classical `Action` for controller (not async), he would have to wait for the result (`Await.result`) before returning a `Result` like `Ok(myResult)`; therefore blocking the Play's default thread pool. Unless he increases the default thread pool, the blocking caused by `Await.result` would slow down the handling of new requests. In the contrary, making controller `async` would allow to pass (and forget for some time) a Future handled with a dedicated ExecutionContext (DBExecutionContext), releasing the default thread for new request handling. What do you think about?

Comment: There is no `Future` because the db call is blocking.  Artificially constructing a `Future` when it's not needed and then not blocking the controller really yields very little benefit since the db call is still blocking.

Comment: By wrapping blocking code in a Future, you can define a specific execution context for this code. Otherwise, blocking threads in 1 action can drastically impact other Actions doing pure CPU while having CPU not fully utilised!

If i understand the article that you linked to correctly, @sadache actually suggests to use a specific execution context for blocking DB calls with a ThreadPool that's the same size as the DB ConnectionPool. His example even uses SQL wrapped inside a Future, which takes this ExecutionContext as an extra (implicit) parameter.
How would you do that without using a future?

Comment: Yeah, creating thread pools specifically for blocking can be a good idea.  Personally I'd use Akka for that.  But in many applications if I've exhausted a thread pool for blocking db calls, then letting more requests into another thread pool doesn't really solve any problems.  Another good read on this front: http://blog.ometer.com/2011/11/13/task-dispatch-and-nonblocking-io-in-scala/

Comment: So when the OP says the db calls are blocking and asks how to make the controller async, do you still think the answer is "don't"? I'm sorry i keep going on about this, James. I think you are very knowledgable and I really value your opinion but i just dont understand why you would encourage blocking code in the controllers. I believe that Play Controllers should be reactive and async and blocking code should not block the default execution context. If this is taught to people from the start, it will safe them time when their app gets bigger / uses more CPU. Or am I wrong in thinking this?

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors.  Is the app still functional when all of the db threads are blocked?  Will all of the db threads ever be blocked?  Is simply increasing the Play thread pools sufficient?  How do you want to handle timeouts?  How many blocked db threads are there per request?

I've updated my answer to express this situationally.