# Play Framework 2.X and blocking database call

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, nonblocking, playframework-2.3

I'm a little confused.

From the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ThreadPools):

> Play default thread pool - This is the default thread pool in which
>   all application code in Play Framework is executed, excluding some
>   iteratees code. It is an Akka dispatcher, and can be configured by
>   configuring Akka, described below. By default, it has one thread per
>   processor.

Does it bring benefit to wrap a blocking database call in a `Future`, the call to the `Future` being itself wrapped by an `async` controller (returning it), in order to let the **default thread pool** handling other users requests?

It would just move the blocking code inside another thread (from a dedicated ExecutionContext), but leave the `Action` unblocked.

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421322/how-to-rewrite-synchronous-controller-to-be-asynchronous-in-play) but I'm not satisfied with the given answer.
Indeed, if I let the database call blocking within the default thread pool, wouldn't it potentially prevent handling other users requests that does not depend on database in the meantime?

Note: My database (Neo4j) hasn't an async driver.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle blocking calls. I can't say which is best, as it would most certainly depend on specific use cases, and require a ton of benchmarking.

By default, Play handles requests using a thread pool with one thread per cpu core. So, if you're running your Play app on a quad-core cpu, for example, it will only be able to handle 4 concurrent requests if they're using blocking calls to the database. So yes, all other incoming requests will have to wait until one of the threads had been freed up.

The simplest solution is to increase the number of threads Play uses to process requests in the default thread pool (in application.conf):

```
play {
   akka {
     akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
     loglevel = WARNING
     actor {
        default-dispatcher = {
           fork-join-executor {
             parallelism-min = 300
             parallelism-max = 300
           }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

The next option is the one you mention in your question--offloading blocking database calls to another `ExecutionContext`. You can configure a separate thread pool within application.conf like so:

```
database-io {
    fork-join-executor {
       parallelism-factor = 10.0
    }
}
```

This will create a 10 threads per cpu core in the pool called `database-io`, and can be accessed within Play like so:

```
val dbExecutor: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("database-io")

val something = Future(someBlockingCallToDb())(dbExecutor)
```

This will allow the default thread pool to handle more requests while it's waiting for the `Future` to complete. A third option would be to use an `Actor` to handle the database calls, but that's more complicated and beyond the scope of this question.

The bottom line is, **yes**, use a larger thread pool or a different `ExecutionContext` for blocking calls, as you **never** want to block in the default thread pool if you can help it.

This is all outlined in the [Play Documentation for Thread Pools](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools). (latest version)

Comment: Nice answer :) Indeed, dedicated actors behind a Router could make the trick too. But I don't understand why the other post evokes: "It you don't have anything to not block on then there isn't any reason to make your controller async". If I use the "ExecutionContext solution", I must have an async controller, do you agree?

Comment: `Action`s are async by default, anyway. `Action.async` is only a convenience for dealing with `Future`s. There were too many negatives in the quoted statement for it to be really clear. I'd stick with the separate `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: Yes I do know. Play is 100% async. `Async` is just a way to handle the future more easily. But if I used the classical `Action`, I would have to make the call to database with a future, then `Await.result` (to obtain the result), then specify the result (like `Ok(myResult)`), since `Action` does not return a `Future[Result]` but simply uses a future internally. And `Await` would make block.